# iCloud mail sync with outlook 2016 on MAC

Tags: icloud, ms-office

I have all the latest software - El Capitan, Outlook 2016 fully patched, and an iCloud account that I can log into (from Safari) using either thisIsMe@icloud.com or thisIsMe@gmail.com with thisIsMyPassword.

I setup Mac Outlook 2016 as per web instructions...

```
E-mail address: thisIsMe@icloud.com
User Name: thisIsMe
Password:  thisIsMyPassword
Incoming Server: imap.mail.me.com:993 (SSL checked)
Outgoing Server: smtp.mail.me.com:587 (SSL checked)
```

I have tried everything... sadly no combination of anything makes it all 'just work'. :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual error? Have you tried using Apple Mail and iCloud Preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The issue was the 2-factor authentication. The solution, go to [Manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage), Edit by security, create an APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORD..

[image]

The rest is self-explanatory. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Thanks for this simple answer. I already started losing my hair to get my account linked.